# Display a custom portlet icon in Application manager of Liferay 6.2 CE

Tags: icons, liferay, portlet

I plan to submit a portlet plugin to Liferay Marketplace. I would like to include an icon, but i have not yet found a guidance to do this. I noticed other portlet plugins have a liferay-releng.properties, and an image is placed in WEB-INF/releng/icons/90x90.png. I also found out in the source code of [PluginSummaryBuilder](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/src-html/com/liferay/portal/tools/PluginsSummaryBuilder.html), it was looking for an icon at WEB-INF/releng/icons/90x90.png. So i added my .png icon here with the recommended size 90 x 90. So far, so good.

But when i deploy the application (.war) in my portal, this icon is not taken into consideration, in the application manager screen the default image is displayed instead (such kaleo example below). I noticed it is the same for some existing marketplace plugins, for example see the screenshot attached: the knowledge-base portlet has its custom icon but Kaleo-web has the default one, though they both have an image defined in their respective WEB-INF/releng/icons/90x90.png.

So here are my questions:

1/ Is there a documentation, or any blog post describing how to add an icon? Otherwise could someone advice?

2/ Why some icons are not displayed in the application manager, such Kaleo example?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: While I can't give you the exact reason for the icon not to appear, note that during upload of your application you'll have to separately upload a 90*90px icon and the marketplace packaging process will do something with it - it might be worth a try if it gets automatically woven into the application in a way that application manager understands.

Comment: Thank you Olaf, i believed we had to package this icon and screenshots directly in the application before the submit. Valuable comment! Though as you mentionned is still does not explain why the icon is not displayed for some plugins in the application manager, when they are displayed in the marketplace such as "Kaleo" example.